# why silverlight libs are in runtime v2.0.50727?

Tags: .net, silverlight

Why is the Silverlight libs built on the .NET runtime version v2.0.50727?
Is there any rational for not having the Silverlight libs in the latest available .net runtime?
Or is it just a completely seperate product, and not possible to use any v4 .net libs within a Silverlight project?

Comment: Which version of Silverlight are you using? It sounds like you may be using 2 or 3, rather than 4...

Comment: @Jon:  Runtime version on a Silverlight library doesn't mean anything, even the SL 4 libraries still have this runtime version.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Interesting... I'd expected the SL4 libs to have a different number. Ah well.

Comment: @Jon: Even in SL 5, which has Version 5.0.5.0, the runtime version is v2.0.50727, as @AnthonyWJones is pointing out, it does not mean anything. I was trying to figure out the rational for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All silverlight libraries carry the same runtime version number.  For Silverlight this version number is meaningless.  Most SL libraries have the version 2.0.5.0 even those that were introduced in SL3.  Some dlls that were introduced at or after SL 4 have 4.0.5.0 as their version.

In reality the version numbers have much less impact in the Silverlight world.  This is no GAC to pull versions of dlls from.  There is little in the way of hunting for dlls when a demand to load a dll is encountered, all the dlls referenced in the deployment are loaded on app start and referenced absolutely.  Its not possible to load more than one version of a dll into the running instances of Silverlight either.